# PHP eval() code returned from mysql query *not working*

Tags: php, mysql, eval

if i take and do something like this:

```
    $p = 10;
    $n = 3;
    $evalstr = "\$f = 0.99 + ((.025 * \$p) * \$n);";
    eval($evalstr);
    echo $f;
```

I get 1.74 displayed, no errors everything is fine, but when I have a mysql table that holds these equations (for the purpose of this example, it is the exact same equation)...like so:

```
    $p = 10;
    $n = 3;
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $math = $result['math'];
        //at this point $math = "\$f = 0.99 + ((.025 * \$p) * \$n);"
        eval($math);
    }
```

I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_STRING in ajax\getprices.php(30) : eval()'d code on line 1

Unsure as to why, if i print of echo $math is it identical to what I have as $evalstr in the first example. $p and $n are actually set from GET variables but even if I set them manually as in the example it does not work.

Comment: Suggestion. Try not to store your PHP in a database. If you have an sql injection vulnerability, someone could totally compromise your entire code base. Not just your database.

Comment: http://ideone.com/T20A4 are you sure $math is really what you say it is?

Comment: Try replacing the `eval()` with `var_dump($math)` and tell us _exactly_ what it prints out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me, that you stored the expression including the escaped *$* in the database. You might try, if it works, if you first remove the slashes:

```
eval(stripslashes($math));
```

I too would recommend to be very careful with storing such code in a database and using *eval* to execute it. There is potential for security holes here. But i assume, you know this.

Comment: this does work, same answer I came up with, I am removing the slashes manually (only 18 equations) and security is no issue here, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it, seems when defining the eval code as a variable I have to escape the $ but when pulling it from mysql as a variable it works if i unescape the $